# Required Field with HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

The problem that I'm having is with the validation of a form. I'm given two text box while both are optional. However, for the server to validate the form one of them has to be filled in. I'm not having a problem with making a field be required (see example below). My man concern is creating the code in order for both textboxes to be optional, but one or the other has to be filled in to validate. I'm not sure if this even has to deal with the code or not. If someone could just give me a place to start that would be greatly appreciated! I'm not asking anyone to do this for me, just give a step in the right direction. Thank you in advance!

Example:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="name" required>
  <input type="text" id="state">
 </body>
</html>
```

Would it be something like this?

```
function validateForm() {
  if (myForm.value == "") {
    alert ("Please enter at least one field");
    return false;
  } 
}
```

Comment: One way is to use jQuery. Set required on both. Then, on the change event on each input create an event handler that tests if the .val() has a length. If so, remove the required attribute of the other input.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! I should've put this in the original post... I can't use jQuery only JavaScript!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @JonasB said, It'll need some javascript something like:

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <script>
    function validateForm(){
        var x = document.getElementById("name");
        var y = document.getElementById("state");
        if(x.value =="" && y.value==""){
            alert ("Please enter at least one field");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
  </script>
</head>
 <body>
   <form onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      <input type="text" id="name">
      <input type="text" id="state">
      <button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do that with pure HTML5. You will need a small JavaScript, which checks on submit if one of the fields is filled.

Comment: I've added what I think might be some progress to the beginning of this question. Would you check it out for me?